# Rangos Case usando Switch C++ en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

tengo un problema y es que mi IDE Visual Studio 2022 me detecta un error en mi codigo de C++, al principio pense que era porque estaba usando el estandar de lenguaje predeterminado que era C++ 14 y cuando investigue al parecer no estaba disponible aun. Pero cambie el estandar de lenguaje y aun sigue mostrando error. En OnlineGBD (Un compilador en linea) el programa funciona correctamente pero en el IDE me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca una imagen de mis propiedades del IDE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo por si alguien mira algo raro, aunque el IDE solo detecta los errores en los CASE, aun asi una disculpa por el desorden del codigo, apenas estoy aprendiendo C++.

```
introducir el código aquí // Librerias
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::setprecision;
using std::setw;
using std::fixed;
using std::string;


int main() {

// declaracion de variables
int nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, edad, diasAsistidos;
string clasificacion;
bool escuelita, bonoExcelencia, bonoVacacional, tutoria;
double promedio;

// constantes
const int DIAS_CLASE = 200;
const double BONO_VACACIONAL_PORCENTAJE = 0.05;
const double BONO_VACACIONAL_TOPE = 0.2;
const double BONO_VACACIONAL_VALOR_POR_EDAD = 325.0;
const double BONO_EXCELENCIA_VALOR = 1000.0;

// contadores y acumuladores
int cantAlumEscuelita = 0;
int cantAlumBonoExcelencia = 0;
int cantAlumBonoVacacional = 0;
int cantEstAprobados = 0;
int cantEstReprobados = 0;
int cantEstConReconocimiento = 0;
double totalBonoExcelencia = 0.0;
double totalBonoVacacional = 0.0;

//h. Complete el programa de manera que pueda realizar las operaciones para varios alumnos.

    //Ingreso de datos (Cantidad de alumnos)

int cantAlumnos;
cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: ";
cin >> cantAlumnos;
for (int i = 1; i <= cantAlumnos; ++i) {

    //a. Determinar el promedio anual de un alumno basado en cuatro notas parciales, clasificar el promedio.

    cout << "\nIngrese las notas del alumno " << i << " (nota1 nota2 nota3 nota4): ";
    cin >> nota1 >> nota2 >> nota3 >> nota4;

    //Calculo del promedio

    promedio = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4) / 4.0;
    string clasificacion;

    int promedioEntero = static_cast<int>(promedio); //Conversion del promedio double a un entero para poder usar switch

    switch (promedioEntero) {
    case 0 ... 69:
        clasificacion = "Reprobado";
        break;
    case 70 ... 74:
        clasificacion = "Regular";
        break;
    case 75 ... 84:
        clasificacion = "Bueno";
        break;
    case 85 ... 94:
        clasificacion = "Muy bueno";
        break;
    case 95 ... 100:
        clasificacion = "Excelente";
        break;
    default:
        clasificacion = "Desconocido";
        break;
    }

    //g.ciclo do-while para iterar hasta que haya una edad correcta

    do {
        cout << "Ingrese la edad del alumno " << i << ": ";
        cin >> edad;
    } while (edad < 5 || edad > 17);


    //b. Ingresar los dias asistidos a clase y ciclo do-while que itere hasta que se ingrese un valor menor o igual a 200.

    do {
        cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de días que asistió a clases el alumno " << i << ": ";
        cin >> diasAsistidos;
    } while (diasAsistidos > 200);

    //b. Calculos para determinar el porcentaje de asistencia basado en los dias asistidos
    double porcentajeAsistencia = static_cast<double>(diasAsistidos) / DIAS_CLASE * 100;

    if (porcentajeAsistencia > 100) {
        porcentajeAsistencia = 100;
    }

    if (porcentajeAsistencia < 0) {
        porcentajeAsistencia = 0;
    }

    if (porcentajeAsistencia > 100) {
        porcentajeAsistencia = 100;
    }

    // c. d. y e. Condicionales y calculos para determinar si aplica al bono vacacional o/y al bono de Excelencia

    escuelita = promedio <= 69;
    bonoExcelencia = promedio >= 95 && porcentajeAsistencia > 90;
    bonoVacacional = promedio > 85;

    if (bonoVacacional) {
        int cantHermanos;
        cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de hermanos en la institución: ";
        cin >> cantHermanos;

        double porcentajeIncremento = cantHermanos * BONO_VACACIONAL_PORCENTAJE;
        if (porcentajeIncremento > BONO_VACACIONAL_TOPE) {
            porcentajeIncremento = BONO_VACACIONAL_TOPE;
        }

        double bonoVacacionalValor = (edad * BONO_VACACIONAL_VALOR_POR_EDAD) * (1 + porcentajeIncremento);
        cout << "Bono Vacacional: Lps. " << bonoVacacionalValor << endl;

        cantAlumBonoVacacional = cantAlumBonoVacacional + 1;
        totalBonoVacacional = totalBonoVacacional + bonoVacacionalValor;
    }

    // f. Determinar si un alumno aplica a tutoria.

    tutoria = (nota1 < 70 && nota2 < 70) && (promedio < 70);

    //Resultados de los alumnos 
    cout << "\nResultados para el alumno " << i << ":\n";
    cout << " ==============================" << endl;
    cout << "Promedio: " << promedio << "\nClasificación: " << clasificacion << "\n";
    cout << "Porcentaje de Asistencia: " << porcentajeAsistencia << "%\n";
    cout << "Va a la Escuelita: ";
    if (escuelita) {
        cout << "Sí";
        cantAlumEscuelita = cantAlumEscuelita + 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "No";
    }
    cout << "\nBono por Excelencia: ";
    if (bonoExcelencia) {
        cout << "Sí";
        cantAlumBonoExcelencia++;
        totalBonoExcelencia = totalBonoExcelencia + BONO_EXCELENCIA_VALOR;
    }
    else {
        cout << "No";
    }
    cout << "\nAplica a Tutoría: ";
    if (tutoria) {
        cout << "Sí";
    }
    else {
        cout << "No";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    if (promedio >= 70) {
        cantEstAprobados++;
        if (promedio >= 95) {
            cantEstConReconocimiento = cantEstConReconocimiento + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        cantEstReprobados = cantEstReprobados + 1;
    }
}

//6. Estudiantes aprobados, reprobados, que fueron a escuelita, con reconocimiento y bono vacacional.

cout << "\nResumen Total:\n";
cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos Aprobados: " << cantEstAprobados << endl;
cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos Reprobados: " << cantEstReprobados << endl;
cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos que fueron a la Escuelita: " << cantAlumEscuelita << endl;
cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos con Reconocimiento (Clasificación Excelente): " << cantEstConReconocimiento << endl;
cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos con Bono Vacacional: " << cantAlumBonoVacacional << endl;
cout << "Cantidad de Alumnos con Bono de Excelencia: " << cantAlumBonoExcelencia << endl;
cout << "Total de Dinero entregado en Bonos de Excelencia: Lps. " << totalBonoExcelencia << endl;
cout << "Total de Dinero entregado en Bonos Vacacionales: Lps. " << totalBonoVacacional << endl;
cout << "==============================================================" << endl;

// 7. Evaluación del Maestro basado en tres criterios (En mi caso escogi dinamismo,puntualidad y Resolucion de dudas)

char evalClase, evalDinamica, asistenciaProfesor;


cout << "\nEvaluación de la Clase del Maestro:\n";
cout << "AVISO! USE MAYUSCULAS PARA EVALUAR (S O N)" << endl;
cout << "==========================================" << endl;
do {
    cout << "¿Es la clase del maestro A. Dinámica? (S/N): ";
    cin >> evalClase;
    if (evalClase != 'S' && evalClase != 'N') {
        cout << "¡Ingresa la letra correcta en mayuscula!" << endl;
    }
} while (evalClase == 's');

do {
    cout << "¿La clase del maestro es B. Puntual? (S/N): ";
    cin >> evalDinamica;
    if (evalDinamica != 'S' && evalDinamica != 'N') {
        cout << "¡Ingresa la letra correcta en mayuscula!" << endl;
    }
} while (evalDinamica == 's');

do {
    cout << "¿El profesor C. Resuelve dudas? (S/N): ";
    cin >> asistenciaProfesor;
    if (asistenciaProfesor != 'S' && asistenciaProfesor != 'N') {
        cout << "¡Ingresa la letra correcta en mayuscula!" << endl;
    }
} while (asistenciaProfesor == 's');

// Clasificar al maestro
string clasificacionProfesor;

// Verificar la clasificación del maestro
if ((evalClase == 'S') && (evalDinamica == 'S') && (asistenciaProfesor == 'S')) {
    clasificacionProfesor = "Excelente";
}
else if ((evalClase == 'S' && evalDinamica == 'S') || (evalClase == 'S' && asistenciaProfesor == 'S') || (evalDinamica == 'S' && asistenciaProfesor == 'S')) {
    clasificacionProfesor = "Regular";
}
else {
    clasificacionProfesor = "Malo";
}


// Imprimir Resumen de la Evaluación al Profesor
cout << "\nResumen de la Evaluación al Profesor:\n";
cout << "Clasificación: " << clasificacionProfesor << "\n";


return 0;
}
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que case-ranges es una [extensión del compilador GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html).

Comment: Te agradezco mucho @FJSevilla llevaba un par de horas intentando solucionarlo pero tu respuesta me llevo al punto exacto de mi problema. 

Por si a alguien tiene la misma duda y le sirve, investigando segun la respuesta de FJSevilla me di cuenta que Clang tambien tiene esa extension de case-ranges, asi que instale el compilador Clang para windows y la compatibilidad de MsBuild con el conjunto de herramientas LLVM (Ambas se pueden encontrar en Obtener herramientas y caracteristicas dentro del mismo Visual Studio) y luego simplemente cambie el toolset a LLVM en las propiedades.